# Yahoo Mail - doesn't show images (only a border)

Tags: email, yahoo

I have been trying yo figure out why Yahoo blocks my images while showing a border on where the image was supposed to show

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3xID.png)

This happens only on images hosted on a specific domain.

For context I have tried the following:

• the same newsletter on different other clients (Gmail, live.com etc.) -> OK, images get displayed

• the same newsletter with images hosted on a different domain -> OK, images get displayed

Thank you

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.